# How to fetch MySQL same record one by one?

Tags: php, mysql

For example:

I have a table name foo which has a column, abc.  In abc column I have 3 same records and I want to show these 3 same records one by one every time page refreshed.

I can not use loop because loop will load all records at one time, and I don't want to show all of these records once. I want to show a single record at a time.

```
id    user_id     abc        link
1     2           google     http://foo.com
2     3           google     http://bar.com
3     2           google     http://baz.com
4     3           bing       http://qar.com
5     1           yahoo      http://quz.com
```

More Explanation: (Update 1)

I want to show only these links which are from google, now the problem is I have google three times in my table. If I use mysql_fetch_assoc() this will give me first record from google but not the other two and I want all googlelinks one by one by refresh.

Comment: It is very unclear what you want. Please clarify.

Comment: @MrSimpleMind Drink up

Comment: @jeremycole I added more explanation hope this will help u.

Comment: @MrSimpleMind I added more explanation hope this will help u.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$_SESSION` variables. Here `$_SESSION['refresh_record']` keeps track of the time the page is refreshed.

So, each time the page is refreshed, this AJAX is run, to increment the session variable.

```
$("#formid").submit(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "UpdateTheSession.php",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(){
          // Do what you want to do when the session has been updated
      }
   });

   return false;
});
```

UpdateTheSession.php

```
$_SESSION['refresh_record'] = $_SESSION['refresh_record'] + 1;
```

Now get the all the records into an array, then:

```
$result[$_SESSION['refresh_record']];
```

The above code should print a picture of what you should do in your mind. Cheers.